# Is it possible to pass generics to a tag function?

Tags: typescript, generics, styled-components

Our typescript configuration is unable to parse syntax related to passing generics into a tag function. On the Styled Components typescript documentation, it recommends passing in prop types like so:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface TitleProps {
  readonly isActive: boolean
}

const Title = styled.h1<TitleProps>`
  color: ${props =>
    props.isActive ? props.theme.colors.main : props.theme.colors.secondary};
`
```

However, when attempting I get typescript compile errors related to the angle bracket syntax:

```
Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'string'.ts(2365)
'TitleProps' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
```

We're on the most recent version of Typescript (3.6). I know that tagged template literals had typescript support going back to 2.9. Is there any way to update our configuration so that typescript knows how ho parse that recommended syntax?

I Googled for anything related to typescript and tag functions or tagged template literals. I can't find anything else related beyond the fact that it should be supported

This very basic implementation also shows the same error:

```js
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
  return arg;
}

identity<string[]>`test`
```

I expect `string[]` to be assigned to the tagged template string argument.

Comment: Is it at all possible that you have multiple versions of typescript installed and for some reason it's using the older one? As a quick test you can add `let foo: unknown;` to your code. The `unknown` type was introduced in 3.0 so if you get an error you're using something older than that.

Comment: @lukasgeiter thanks for the help! We don't appear to have multiple versions of typescript running (just did as search through the yarn.lock file).

Comment: @lukasgeiter it appears the issue is actually related to the VSCode TSLint plugin. Double checking the console output, it is fine with `unknown` type, but it still shows an error in the editor: `Cannot find name 'unknown'.`. Upon further inspection apparently the tag function issue is the same: typescript is fine, but TSLint can't seem to parse that syntax. Considering that TSLint is deprecated, I'll try migrating to ESLint and see if that resolves the issue

Comment: I see. I can say that in my project using TSLint I don't have such an issue. Could also be because of different versions though. Considering the deprecation of TSLint it probably makes sense to migrate to ESLint anyway.